# CentOS 7 installation falls back to text-mode on Parallels Server Mac VM

Tags: centos, parallels

Every time I am trying to install CentOS 7 in Parallels Server Mac, the installation wizard falls back to text-mode. I am getting this error:

> X startup failed, falling back to text mode

[image]

Default installation process is just working fine with previous version e.g. CentOS 6 or 5. How can I use the GUI-based installation? Do I have to load additional graphic drivers?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, it looks like the built-in graphic drivers do not work with X. Can't you choose a different virtual GPU in paralells?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no option to select a different GPU. Is there any way to load or add a generic video card software for the CentOS installation

Answer (score 1):

Disabling 3D Acceleration in the VM settings made the graphical installer work for me, otherwise the installer was getting stuck on the anaconda text screen with CentOS7-2009 in Parallels Desktop 17.

Comment: Confirm with Parallel Desktop 18 and RHEL 7.