# Boot CentOS7 in graphical mode

Tags: centos

I recently purchased an HP workstation. Now I want to install CentOS to dual boot with windows 10.

I make the pendrive with the DVD image of CentOS7, and boot into the laptop.

Then I get back to 1995 with a text only setup.

it says:

`X startup failed, falling back to text mode`

Why do I get this? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

But can you proceed with text installation? You really need the graphical environment during the install? If you are able to go back to 1995 in your memory, i'm pretty sure you will handle a text mode install and get your desktop environment installed right after you finish the setup. There is already a topic about this here on U&L:

- [How to install Desktop Environments on CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7)

It's hard to debug installer related issues, and you will get nowhere losing time to try to figure out why you graphic card is not supported on installer.

Your other option is to start a `install system with basic video driver`. This will use basic vga drivers and should be less error prone.

**Related Stuff:**

- [CentOS Forums: X startup failed, falling back to text mode" during CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD dual boot install with Windows 10](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58815)
- [X Startup failed, falling back to text mode - still no answers.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313960/x-startup-failed-falling-back-to-text-mode)
- [CentOS 7 installation falls back to text-mode on Parallels Server Mac VM - still no answers.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226262/centos-7-installation-falls-back-to-text-mode-on-parallels-server-mac-vm)

Comment: I did go through the typical stackexchange answers... I figured out that the problem was the noveau drivers, so I'll try your solution and see f it works. BTW, I need to create 14 partitions, so the text mode is something I really want to avoid.

Comment: Good luck with that. I should use basic drivers to avoid thinkering with video issues just to have a pretty installer instead of using a generic vga graphical install... This is somehow what everyone recomends. About the partitions, use `lvm`(dunno if `btrfs` is considered stable) or you will regret if you could not expand further when you face disk space issues... Avoid `xfs` if you want to shrink partitions anytime in future.